# WSO2 API Manager - There are available updates

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using the last release version of wso2 API Manager and in log show some messages of updates avaiable:

```
api-manager           | [2021-02-26 18:09:34,042]  INFO - CallHomeExecutor 
api-manager           | ..............................................................................
api-manager           | There are 220 updates available for the product 'wso2am-3.2.0'.[WARNING] There
api-manager           | are 16 critical security updates for the product 'wso2am-3.2.0'. WSO2 strongly
api-manager           | recommends to apply these updates in production as soon as possible.
api-manager           | ..............................................................................
api-manager           | [2021-02-26 18:09:34,242]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  : https://localhost:9443/carbon/
```

My question is: Is there any way to download this updates without using WSO2 update tool? Because WSO2 update tool is only free for 90 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the patch updates, you need to get the wso2 subscription. Otherwise, you need to wait for the next release or you need to build the product from the source code in GitHub(Building the source code in Github is not recommended for the production).